# loading images from array list using picasso library

Tags: android, arrays, picasso

hi im still new to android 
i was displaying some dummy images in a grid view, i have a custom adapter that uses a view holder, it puts a string array and type array into an array list and displays it in the gridview this all works fine, 
then i realised my images i wanted to use were far too large and found the picasso library, seems very powerful and easy to use but im unsure what to pass into the load method as it wants a type array and my type array is in an array list im sure this is a simple fix but i cant see it,
my images are in the app

here is my imageId and viewholder class

```
 class imageIds
{
    int imageId;
    String imageNames;

    imageIds(int imageId, String imageNames)
    {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.imageNames = imageNames;
    }
}
class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView myView;
    ViewHolder(View view){
        myView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}
```

this is the beginning of my adapter where i declare and initialize my arrays

```
 class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        ArrayList<imageIds> list;
    Context context;
    myAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    list = new ArrayList<imageIds>();
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    String[] tempWallpaperNames = res.getStringArray(R.array.wallpaper_list);

        int[] tempWallPaperImages = {R.drawable.ic_home,R.drawable.ic_photos,R.drawable.ic_home,
                R.drawable.ic_photos,R.drawable.ic_photos,R.drawable.ic_photos,R.drawable.ic_home,
                R.drawable.ic_home,R.drawable.ic_photos,R.drawable.ic_home};
            for (int i = 0; i<10;i++)
            {
                imageIds tempWallpaper = new imageIds(tempWallPaperImages[i],tempWallpaperNames[i]);
                list.add(tempWallpaper);
            }
    }
```

and here is my adapter get view method

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_images,parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
          holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        imageIds wallPapers = list.get(position);
        holder.myView.setImageResource(wallPapers.imageId);

        holder.myView.setTag(wallPapers);

        Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(imageIds[position])
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_photos)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
                .noFade().resize(120,120)
                .centerCrop().into(holder.myView);
        return holder.myView;


        return row;
    }
}
```

android studio is telling me an expression is expected here

```
.load(imageIds[position])
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` expects the actual image filename or a resourceId.

i'm assuming the `imageNames` holds the location/filename or you could use the `imageId`.

change

```
.load(imageIds[position])
```

To

```
.load(imageIds[position].imageNames) or .load(imageIds[position].imageId)
```

**Update**

You are already using `list.get(position)` so you are only returning one item in the wallPapers variable.

So the code should be `.load(wallPapers.imageId)`

Comment: Okay that makes sense thank you but still saying expression expected, tried a couple variations as I thought it may be .imageId no success

Comment: @MartinSeal Can you share the variations?

Comment: @MartinSeal wow .. i can see the error now ... i'm updating my answer now.

Comment: @MartinSeal I've updated my answer. you should use `.load(imageIds.imageId)`

Comment: That's awesome thank you although now I have a non static field cannot be referenced from a static context error @scartag

Comment: @MartinSeal wow.. i see your point .. it should be `wallPapers.imageId` updating my answer to reflect that as well.